# Am unable to get the text "Ready" from below code using Selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium, webdriver

I first need to locate the element "Ready" and then check if its displayed on the screen. Please help

html code:-

```html
<div class="sf-element sf-element-text-box sfpc-left" style="float: left;" title="Ready ">Ready </div>
```

Here's what i have tried

First Try:-

```cs
WebElement search = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("span[title=\"Ready \"]"));
if(search.isDisplayed()){ . I will proceed with other things here.... }
```

Second Try:-

```cs
WebElement search = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(text(),'Ready ')]"));
if(search.isDisplayed()){. I will proceed with other things here.... }
```

But this is not working throws exception.. no element found. please help

Comment: Not able to add the HTML code, here is the code                                              <div class="sf-element sf-element-text-box sfpc-left" style="float: left;" title="Ready ">Ready </div>

Comment: Your text inside a div and you are using span which is wrong.. try this xpath  "//div[contains(text(), 'Ready ')]"

Comment: Is there a reason you are trying to find the element before checking if it is visible? Is there any actions you take on the element between those two steps? If not you could use a WebDriverWait and an expected condition to do both steps at once.

Comment: Yes you are right.. am waiting for the condition where it is found and it is visible. then am taking up my action items further. but currently am waiting in a while.. will check using WebDriverWait. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for a span element:

```
By.cssSelector("span[title=\"Ready \"]")
```

But your html shows a div element:

```
<div title="Ready ">Ready </div>
```

Change your locator to:

```
By.cssSelector("div[title=\"Ready \"]")
```

Answer (score 0):

C#

IWebElement test = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("div[title=\"Ready \"]")); Console.WriteLine(test.Text);

**demo:**

```
        IWebDriver driver;
        string url = "http://localhost:58807/Test1.html";
        var options = new InternetExplorerOptions();
        options.RequireWindowFocus = true;
        options.IntroduceInstabilityByIgnoringProtectedModeSettings = true;
        options.IgnoreZoomLevel = true;
        string path = Environment.CurrentDirectory;
        driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(path, options); 
        TimeSpan span = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60);

        driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(span);
        driver.Manage().Timeouts().SetPageLoadTimeout(span);
        driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(url);

        IWebElement test = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("div[title=\"Ready \"]"));
        Console.WriteLine(test.Text);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
//*[contains(concat(' ', @title, ' '), ' Ready ') and contains(text(), 'Ready')]
```

try the above xpath in `driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(concat(' ', @title, ' '), ' Ready ') and contains(text(), 'Ready')]"))`

Also beware of spaces!!

**Edit**: this above xpath works even if the spaces in title attributes are removed

Comment: your answer is too complicated when the only problem with his code is that he's looking for a span while his element is a div. It's completely unnecessary to use that wildcard concatenated xpath locator.